# Ubuntu 22.04 Can't Stop NFS Service When Shutting Down - Still Used By Zoneminder Service

Tags: shutdown, nfs, zoneminder

I have a KVM guest that is running Zoneminder. I have configured this guest to use an NFS to store all the event data (recorded videos) to an NFS for various reasons. Unfortunately, if I send the KVM command to shutdown the guest, e.g.:

```bash
sudo virsh shutdown my-zoneminder-guest
```

... then it takes an age to shutdown because it fails to unmount the NFS filesystem...

[image]

... and we end up waiting until the NFS timeout is triggered and the guest kills the NFS.

[image]

I'm pretty sure that the issue is that Zoneminder is configured to use the NFS, because if I manually stop the Zoneminder service before issuing the `virsh shutdown` command on the hypervisor, then the guest shutsdown very quickly without issue.

In case it matters, my NFS is mounted through the following entry in my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
192.168.1.5:/media/extra_storage        /mnt/nfs        nfs     auto    0        0
```

### Question

Is there a way to tweak the Ubuntu 22 server so that it knows that it needs to shutdown the Zoneminder service before it attempts to unmount the NFS filesystem? Perhaps that is the wrong way to resolve this problem and there is a better solution?